# ngb-tab [hidden]="tab.hidden" not work

Tags: angular, hidden, ng-bootstrap

Why does not work [hidden] = "tab.hidden"?

```html
<ngb-tabset [activeId]="activeTab" (tabChange)="activeTab = $event.nextId">
        <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [id]="tab.id" [disabled]="tab.disabled" [hidden]="tab.hidden">
          <ng-template ngbTabTitle>{{tab.title}}</ng-template>
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            <p style="margin: 20px">Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth
              master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh
              dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum
              iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
      </ngb-tabset>
```

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/api#NgbTab), `hidden` is not an 'input' property defined on the selector `ngb-tab`. If you simply want to make it `hidden` (and still have the element in DOM, try setting the `display` style on that element using `ngStyle` (see [this](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#how-to-use) for more info on `ngStyle`),

```
<ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [id]="tab.id" [disabled]="tab.disabled" [ngStyle]="{'display': tab.hidden ? 'none' : 'block'}">
// if the default style is not 'block' then assign appropriate style to the else-case for 'display' style above, 
// like may be 'inline-block' instead of 'block'
```

If you do want the element to be removed altogether from DOM instead of just being hidden, use `*ngIf` instead. But since no 2 structural directives (`ngFor` and `ngIf` in this case) can be present together on an element, wrap the `ngFor` outside in an `ng-container` like this,

```
<ngb-tabset [activeId]="activeTab" (tabChange)="activeTab = $event.nextId">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
  <ngb-tab [id]="tab.id" [disabled]="tab.disabled" *ngIf="tab.hidden">
   <ng-template ngbTabTitle>{{tab.title}}</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
     <p style="margin: 20px">
      Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.
     </p>
   </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
 </ng-container>
</ngb-tabset>
```

For all these cases to work, you also need to set the `hidden` property of each element in `tabs` object to a corresponding boolean value of either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

set in component tab.hidden = true or false
`[hidden]="true" or
[hidden]="false"`

Comment: Hi, still not work <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [id]="tab.id" [disabled]="tab.disabled" [hidden]="true">

Answer (score 0):

My solution modify tabset.js - add `'hidden': [{ type: Input },],`:

```
`NgbTab.propDecorators = {
'id': [{ type: Input },],
'title': [{ type: Input },],
'disabled': [{ type: Input },],
'hidden': [{ type: Input },],
'contentTpl': [{ type: ContentChild, args: [NgbTabContent,] },],
'titleTpl': [{ type: ContentChild, args: [NgbTabTitle,] },],
};`
```

add `[class.hidden]=\"tab.hidden\"` to template:

`template: "\n    <ul [class]=\"'nav nav-' + type + (orientation == 'horizontal'?  ' ' + justifyClass : ' flex-column')\" role=\"tablist\">\n

<li class=\"nav-item\" *ngFor=\"let tab of tabs\" 
[class.hidden]=\"tab.hidden\">\n`

and add to styles.css

`.hidden {
     display: none !important;
    }`

M.

Answer (score 0):

If the approved answer doesn't work for you, 
You can just put your `ngb-tab` which is to be hidden in a `div` tag and put your `*ngIf` condition for that particular div which works fine.

```
<div *ngIf="condtion">
  <ngb-tab title="Sample Tab">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</div>
```